# angular js the deugger doesn't get into the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

when i debug my controller, it stuck at the initialization of the controller and doesn't get past it
here is the app

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
```

and here is the controller and it's service

```
app.controller('UsersController', function ($scope, UsersService) {
$scope.User = [];
$scope.Image = [];
$scope.CV = [];
alert("Controller");
$scope.GetUserProfile = function (ID) {
    alert("in");
    UsersService.GetUserData(ID, function (Result) {
        if (Result.success == true) {
            $scope.User = Result.Content;
        }
    });
}
});

app.service('UsersService', function ($http) {
    this.GetUserData = function (UserID,callback) {
        var req = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:7598/tb/Profile/GetProfileByID',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'No Authentication'
            },
            params: {
                'ID': UserID
            }
        }
        $http(req).success(callback);
    }
});
```

and in html i reference the Angular js file and the App file and the Controller file

here is the HTML

```
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/ScriptControllers/MainApp.js"></script>
<script src="~/ScriptControllers/UsersController.js"></script>
<div class="card hovercard" ng-controller="UsersController">
    <div class="card-background" ng-init="GetUserProfile(5)">
```

Comment: any errors you find in console in debugger

Comment: probably you are not calling the GetUserProfile

Comment: did you got alert "in" in your program

Comment: Please post your code to the [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/) As this might be an issue related to the HTML as well

Comment: No errors in the deugger

Comment: here is the HTML part for this section

<script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/ScriptControllers/MainApp.js"></script>
<script src="~/ScriptControllers/UsersController.js"></script>
<div class="card hovercard" ng-controller="UsersController">
    <div class="card-background" ng-init="GetUserProfile(5)">

it doesn't alert anyting, when i debug and i breakpoint at the initialization of the controller, it stops there but when i click F10, it just go to the service then continues.

Comment: I updated the post and added the HTML for that section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you're missing an ng-app directive in the html, according to the html and js code you've posted. The browser just parses the js code but does not execute it.

```
     <body ng-app="app"> ... </body>
```

Working example of your code: [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/IpIzF2YMXnIByhDRdo3R?p=preview)